# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error in Appium

Tags: java, automation, appium

I am getting this error consistently when executing my code using appium 1.7.2. The error occurs on this method ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH);

Java client - 5.0.4
Appium - 1.7.2
TestNG - 6.11
Device Samsung galaxy J7 (7.x version)

Appium server log link - [Appium log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alkaffkhan28/f1c1341af1dfaa903124ec56e66f8a17/raw/593eb4aa19b54adc5f45c3597b785a9b5bbb87a4/appium_server_log.txt)

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution/workaround for this?

Comment: I fixed this by downgrading Appium version from 1.7.2 to 1.7.1.